# Accessing Microsoft SharePoint excel file using python

Tags: python, azure, dataframe, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

Can Some one explain how I can take my company shared data from store in Microsoft SharePoint, using python?
How I create connection my company SharePoint particular data store location, using python?
Because I need to get some excel files from SharePoint folder, into pandas data frame so, do that thing initially I need to create connection to my company SharePoint. I refer different document but still I couldn't find correct way to do that task.

If some tell me step by step for following task then I can work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import pandas as pd
import requests

TENANT_ID = ''
CLIENT = ''
KEY = ''
siteId= ''
itemId =''

tempPath = 'd:/home/test.csv'

cred = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    client_secret = KEY,
    tenant_id = TENANT_ID
)

access_token = cred.get_token("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default").token

#download csv to local 

reqFileURL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%s/drive/items/%s/content' % (siteId,itemId)
fileContent = requests.get(url = reqFileURL,headers={'Authorization':'Bearer ' + access_token})

f = open(tempPath,'wb')
f.write(fileContent.content)
f.close()

data = pd.read_csv(tempPath)
print(data)
```

Result:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Basically, I use [this MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to download CSV content.
If you not sure how to get CSV itemID, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
Pls note, before you run this demo, you should make sure that your sp has been granted permissions the API doc indicated, like:
[image]